# Does a contractible locally connected continuum have an fixed point property?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I'm surprised that I can't find any research on this topic. Maybe it's too obvious? Kinoshita proved that [contractible continuum do not have FPP](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm40/fm4019.pdf), but his example is not locally connected. Maybe if we add this to the conditions it will have FPP?

P.S. [Continuum as a nonempty compact connected metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology))

P.S.2. Asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710234/does-a-contractible-locally-connected-continuum-have-an-fixed-point-property/4710322?noredirect=1#comment9990155_4710322), but smart guy in comments to his answer advise me publish it here

Comment: This is a difficult (and I hope still open) problem because even for convex compact sets in linear metric spaces the proof of FPP (done by Robert Cauty in 2005) is highly nontrivial and required the theory of algebraic ANR's (a homological modification of the classical Borsuk's theory of ANRs).

Comment: On the other hand, countably-dimensional contractible locally contractible compact spaces are absolute retracts, so have FPP. So, if a counterexample exists, it should be infinite-dimensional contractible compact, locally contractible and not AR. Such spaces indeed exist, but as far as I know it is not known whether every compact convex set in a linear metric space is an absolute retract. Probably not, but none know how to construct such an example.

Comment: @TarasBanakh: My guess is that there are counter-examples to the OP which is only asking for local connectivity rather than local contractibility, plus global contractibility, of course.  This should be much simpler than a counter-example to the problem you are suggesting.

Comment: @TarasBanakh yeah, problem is that local-contractibility is not a condition

Comment: @TarasBanakh like cone over havai ring for R^3, or same cone over infinite torus for R^4. Feels like counter-example exists, but i don't know

Comment: Cones of this type cannot be counterexamples because for every $\varepsilon>0$ they admit an $\varepsilon$-closed to the identity retraction $r:X\to Y$ onto an AR-subspace $Y\subseteq X$ of $X$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh then what about $A:=(Hawaii \ Ring \times [0;1]) \cup E^2$.
Such that factor $A/E^2$ is a cone over Hawaii Ring. There is no retraction for each $\epsilon > 0$ on AR. Maybe if cone over space $B$ have an FPP follows that such construction like $A$ over space $B$ have an FPP?